# Can't align TMS on OpenLayers Map

Tags: openlayers-2, tile-map-service

I would like to add this TMS layer as my baseLayer. You can see [the layer specs here](http://pregeoegl.msp.gouv.qc.ca/cgi-wms/mapcache.fcgi/tms/1.0.0/carte_gouv_qc_public@EPSG_3857/)

I am doing like this to create the layer:

```
var tmsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS(
    "Gouvernement du Quebec",
    "http://pregeoegl.msp.gouv.qc.ca/cgi-wms/mapcache.fcgi/tms/",
   { layername: 'carte_gouv_qc_public@EPSG_3857', 
     type: "png", 
     serviceVersion:"1.0.0",
     gutter:0,
     buffer:0,
     isBaseLayer:true,
     tileOrigin: new OpenLayers.LonLat(-20037508.342789,-20037508.342789),
     numZoomLevels: null,
     maxZoomLevel: 16,
     minZoomLevel: 4,     
     zoomOffset:0,
     animate: true,
     visibility: true,
     transitionEffect: 'null',
     units:"m",
     maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.342789,-20037508.342789,20037508.342789,20037508.342789),
     projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857".toUpperCase()),
     sphericalMercator: true
     }
  );
```

As I am using an API that automatically create OpenLayers Map, I can't create the map myself but I use to modify it after loaded. I know that sucks, but you can see the map object definition in the console from this web site: https://carto48dev.mels.gouv.qc.ca/Infogeo/test/wms.html

What is the cause of the misalignment between the TMS layer and the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inspecting your sample url, I see that tiles called are coming from https://pregeoegl.msp.gouv.qc.ca/cgi-wms/mapcache.fcgi/tms/1.0.0/carte_gouv_qc_public@EPSG_3857/4/13/28.png.

I should be able to make a getCapabilities request (see http://mapserver.org/mapcache/services.html to understand how I deduced it) with https://pregeoegl.msp.gouv.qc.ca/cgi-wms/mapcache.fcgi/tms/1.0.0/ and I don't get anything except an error.

IMO, your problem is on server side not on OpenLayers side. It can come from network issue, a mapcache misconfiguration or a configuration issue at Apache level (previous url send back a 403 error `Forbidden. You don't have permission to access /cgi-wms/mapcache.fcgi/tms/1.0.0/ on this server.system issue`)

**Edit**, due to feedback, the issue is not the server at the end.

Try code below on your sample in the console: it works but I removed some constraints (I think main issue = no resolution on your code side)

```
olmap.removeLayer(tmsLayer);

var tmsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS( "Gouvernement du Quebec",
  "http://pregeoegl.msp.gouv.qc.ca/cgi-wms/mapcache.fcgi/tms/", {
    layername: 'carte_gouv_qc_public@EPSG_3857',
    type: "png",
    serviceVersion:"1.0.0",
    gutter:0,
    buffer:0,
    isBaseLayer:true,
    transitionEffect:'resize',
    tileOrigin: new OpenLayers.LonLat(-20037508.342789,-20037508.342789),
    resolutions:[156543.03392804099712520838,78271.51696402048401068896,39135.75848201022745342925,19567.87924100512100267224,9783.93962050256050133612,4891.96981025128025066806,2445.98490512564012533403,1222.99245256282006266702,611.49622628141003133351,305.74811314070478829308,152.87405657035250783338,76.43702828517623970583,38.21851414258812695834,19.10925707129405992646,9.55462853564703173959,4.77731426782351586979,2.38865713391175793490,1.19432856695587897633,0.59716428347793950593],
    zoomOffset:0,
    units:"m",
    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.342789,-20037508.342789,20037508.342789,20037508.342789),
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913".toUpperCase()),
    sphericalMercator: true
  }
);
olmap.addLayer(tmsLayer);
```

For resolutions, I reused [this tip](http://trac.mapfish.org/trac/mapfish/wiki/HowTosTips#GenerateTileCacheresolutionsfromOpenLayersscales) but it's also possible to get them directly from [MapCache config code](https://github.com/mapserver/mapcache/blob/master/mapcache.xml.sample#L106). Resolutions on client and server side should be the same. This rule only true for Spherical Mercator because fixed parameters.

Comment: the TMS are restricted to an area, not the whole world, thats why I have the pink tiles in the sample because the z/x/y.png called by my map are wrong. Look this link to see the server is working: https://pregeoegl.msp.gouv.qc.ca/cgi-wms/mapcache.fcgi/tms/1.0.0/carte_gouv_qc_public@EPSG_3857/4/5/10.png

Comment: wow that was the problem! thank you! it is working now as you can see !

Comment: where did you take those values for the resolutions?